# How to receive ajax json data in a codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On the client side I have :

```
var postData = {
    "id" : id,
    "message" : message
};

console.log(postData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/function",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(){
        alert(id + ' ' + message);
    }
});
```

This appears to be working properly as I can see the correct post parameters in chrome dev tools. In my codeigniter controller I have tried:

```
echo 'postid' . $_POST['id'].' '.$_POST['message'];

$postData=$this->input->post('id');

var_dump($postData); exit;
```

I'm getting:

```
Message: Undefined index: id
Message: Undefined index: message

boolean(false)
```

the `$_POST` array is empty.

How can I fix this? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you may add `dataType:'json'` in your ajax options

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "controller/function",
       data: postData,
       dataType:'json',
       success: function(){
           alert(id + ' ' + message);
       }
});
```

Comment: try to add contentType attribute as well.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried the answer but it doesn't work. I'd like to add a contentType , but what should it be set to. Ali, what should I json_decode?

Comment: what ci version do you use?

Comment: I m using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: it does work here....```<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var id = 123, message = 'test', postData = { "id" : id, "message" : message };
console.log(postData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "test/do_action",
        data: postData, 
        success: function(){
            alert(id + ' ' + message);
        }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>```

Comment: Yeah, mine says it works too, but when I do var_dump($_post) I get array(0) { }

Comment: i mean it works fine with `test/do_action`,     ```public function index() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

    public function do_action() {
        echo 'postid' . $_POST['id'].' '.$_POST['message'];
        $postData=$this->input->post('id');
        var_dump($postData);
    }``` it returns `postid123 teststring(3) "123"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your CI to use CSRF protection? If yes, you will need to include the CSRF field and value to your POST request.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/function",
    data: postData, 
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.id + ' ' + data.message);
    }
});
```

ajax return json object in data , you forgot to written data in function

Comment: Please add some explanation to the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType:'json'` parameter for the `$.ajax` at client side.